# Ускорение обработки очереди

Tags: python, многопоточность, очередь

Есть некоторая очередь, и функция,  которая занимается обработкой элементов этой очереди. Код для примера:

```
import queue

q = queue.Queue()
for i in range(1000):
    q.put(i)


def queue_preparation():
    while not q.empty():
        item = q.get()
        do_somthing(item)


queue_preparation()
```

Проблема в том, что на одну итерацию уходит около 0.5 секунд, а элементов в очереди может быть очень много. Можно ли как-то ускорить этот процесс? Я пытался создавать отдельные потоки, но это не прибавило скорости обработки.

```
threads = [threading.Thread(target=queue_preparation)]

for th in threads:
    th.start()
    
for th in threads:
    th.join()
```

Comment: вам для чего нужна очередь?

Comment: Что бы потоки дали выигрыш их должно быть примерно столько сколько ядер. И еще вопрос что за функция, какие операции она выполняет. Может статься что из за GIL ваши потоки одновременно работать не будут и потребуются отдельные процессы. И раз у вас есть очередь, то надо было бы заменить ее на очередь из threading, запустить столько потоков сколько ядер и в каждом потоке читать очередь и выполнять работу

Comment: функция do_somthing выполняет запрос к api, а item это айдишник

Comment: Можно увидеть рекльный код?

Comment: do_somthing делайте в многопоток.